# Using UTF-8 to open file for reading

Tags: python, utf-8, readlines

I am using the below code but need to open it for reading with utf-8 specified. How would I do that please?

```
infile = file(logPath)
lines = infile.readlines()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `open` function of [codecs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#codecs.open) module:

```
import codecs

with codecs.open(logPath, encoding='utf8') as infile:
    lines = infile.readlines()
```

By default the `codecs.open` function, open the file in `rb` (read binary) mode:

> def open(filename, mode='rb', encoding=None, errors='strict',
>   buffering=1):
>
> ```
>     ...
>     Files are always opened in binary mode, even if no binary mode
>     was specified. This is done to avoid data loss due to encodings
>     using 8-bit values. The default file mode is 'rb' meaning to
>     open the file in binary read mode.
> ```

Comment: Can I use this infile = open(logPath, encoding='utf8')

Comment: This gives me error: infile = open(logPath, encoding='utf8')
TypeError: 'encoding' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Comment: Now using infile = codecs.open(logPath, encoding='utf8') Anyone see any problems with this?

Comment: I don't see problems? Do you have problems?

Comment: No, in `Python 2`, you can't use `open(logPath, encoding='utf8')`, because it's a built-in [open](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) function, and is different from `codecs.open` function.
But in `Python 3` you can use the built-in [open](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) function for that, however it is still different from `codecs.open` function.